# Joining methods in Pandas. Why so many?

Tags: python, pandas

From the way I understand it, there are several equivalent methods for solving the [**joining problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_join) in Pandas:

- [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat)
- [`df.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append)
- [`df.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join)
- [`df.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge)

There is also the new [query language/method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental).

Is it correct to assume that [`df.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) can be used as a universal method to solve all **merge/join problems** that can be solved with the other methods?

If so, why does Pandas provide the other methods? Speed/conveniency?

Comment: ``join`` is a convenience method that uses ``merge``; ``append`` is a convenience method that uses ``concat``. ``concat`` is for gluing together structures that doesn't need merging logic, while ``merge`` uses fuller logic (and as a result is 'more complicated')

Comment: Thanks @Jeff - would it be fair to say that `merge` uses a fuller logic than `join`? What about the new [query language](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental)? Does it support an even richer logic/algebra?

Comment: No the query language is mainly for selection. join is implemented using merge, just take a look at the code, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L3543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.merge` can be used to solve everything if you think like someone who knows about databases.

The docs refer to [Database-style DataFrame joining/merging](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

If you don't know anything about databases then you should be able to understand the other functions to a sufficient extent to achieve your goals.